# JFree Barchart DefaultCategoryDataset values getting replaced

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jfreechart

While creating the barchart, i fill dataset in below way

```
DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

dataset.setValue(40, "ram", "sunday");
dataset.setValue(50, "ram", "monday");
dataset.setValue(40, "arun", "sunday");
dataset.setValue(50, "arun", "sunday");
```

In the last statement, the value is `50,arun,sunday` and in the previous statement, the value is `40,arun,sunday` .. Here in the dataset the value 50 always been considered and value 40 is always overridden.

I need to retain it still.Not sure how to do it. Is there anything i am missing ?? Please help

Comment: Have you considered using a stacked bar? That would allow you to have two values for the same category.

Comment: I suggested stacked bar chart and client rejected this proposal :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DefaultCategoryDataset` uses internally [DefaultKeyedValues2D](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/gjdoc/org/jfree/data/DefaultKeyedValues2D.html) store the values.

As said in Java doc of [DefaultKeyedValues2D#setValue](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/gjdoc/org/jfree/data/DefaultKeyedValues2D.html#setValue%3aNumber%3aComparable%3aComparable).

> Adds or updates a value.

That is why your value will get updated if you use same `key`. Key here refers to `arun`

Comment: Yes. It will update previous record only. You can delete if exist and then add new.

Comment: gave an round-around solution. before filling the dataset, i used `dataset.getRowIndex("arun")` and if there is any value, i added SPACE to it and made it appear in the chart ;)